# Update custom device tree on yocto

Tags: yocto, openembedded, device-tree

I am using the sama5d27-wlsom1-ek board for my demo and I am trying to make changes to the device tree.

So far I have compiled core-image-minimal and find my dtb files are generated in

```
/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/build/arch/arm/boot/dts
```

folder.

Also I find many different dts files in

```
build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/arch/arm/boot/dts
```

But where does my machine get device tree files if they are generated inside the build folder and if I use my custom dts file how do I update them?

I want to build the image using my custom.dts file where I enable certain peripherals and disable the ones not required. (A test to customize dtb's in future).

I tried different methods found here
[How to use an own device tree and modified kernel config in Yocto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347808/how-to-use-an-own-device-tree-and-modified-kernel-config-in-yocto)
as well as
[Quick rebuild of device tree only with Yocto/bitbake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917745/quick-rebuild-of-device-tree-only-with-yocto-bitbake)

I created a new `meta-local` layer and added it to `bblayer`
followed by `recipetool` command to add my dts file to the new layer. Added `KERNEL_DEVICETREE += "custom.dtb"` to the `.bbappend` file generated inside meta-local and then run `bitbake` build image command so far
But, I seem to run into the following errors when I try to build the image.

```
    Loading cache: 100% |############################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 3474 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |##########################################| Time: 0:00:00
Parsing of 2309 .bb files complete (2307 cached, 2 parsed). 3476 targets, 358 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd"
DISTRO               = "poky-atmel"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1.7"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa5 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "dunfell:97a9f30f1c457c55bf0c791d0466ff8620110a49"
meta-oe              
meta-networking      
meta-webserver       
meta-python          
meta-initramfs       = "dunfell:2915810edbb6599051e30efb3b7f805665ddcc23"
meta-atmel           = "dunfell:d6e30f2c0e3592ed11f3a4c8380a14d0a9066ba6"
meta-multimedia      = "dunfell:2915810edbb6599051e30efb3b7f805665ddcc23"
meta-aws             = "dunfell:2e2a1c65603dc5d11349e25dc9470a65cbeb8e65"
meta-freshair        
meta-local           
workspace            = "dunfell:97a9f30f1c457c55bf0c791d0466ff8620110a49"

Initialising tasks: 100% |#######################################| Time: 0:00:04
Sstate summary: Wanted 294 Found 262 Missed 32 Current 2095 (89% match, 98% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: linux-at91-5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: linux-at91-5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/temp/run.do_compile.57871' failed with exit code 1:
  GEN     Makefile
  CALL    /home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  CALL    /home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  Kernel: arch/arm/boot/Image is ready
  Kernel: arch/arm/boot/zImage is ready
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/boot/dts/new_name.dtb'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/Makefile:1265: new_name.dtb] Error 2
make: *** [/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/Makefile:179: sub-make] Error 2
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/temp/log.do_compile.57871
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: KBUILD_BUILD_TIMESTAMP: Thu Jan 14 12:54:56 UTC 2021
| NOTE: make -j 12 HOSTCC=gcc  -isystem/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 HOSTCPP=gcc  -E HOSTCXX=g++  -isystem/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 zImage CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mno-thumb-interwork -marm -fuse-ld=bfd -fmacro-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0=/usr/src/debug/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0=/usr/src/debug/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source=/usr/src/kernel   LD=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld.bfd
|   GEN     Makefile
|   CALL    /home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
|   CALL    /home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/scripts/checksyscalls.sh
|   CHK     include/generated/compile.h
|   Kernel: arch/arm/boot/Image is ready
|   Kernel: arch/arm/boot/zImage is ready
| NOTE: make -j 12 HOSTCC=gcc  -isystem/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 HOSTCPP=gcc  -E HOSTCXX=g++  -isystem/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at91-sama5d27_wlsom1_ek.dtb CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mno-thumb-interwork -marm -fuse-ld=bfd -fmacro-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0=/usr/src/debug/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0=/usr/src/debug/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source=/usr/src/kernel   LD=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld.bfd
| NOTE: make -j 12 HOSTCC=gcc  -isystem/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 HOSTCPP=gcc  -E HOSTCXX=g++  -isystem/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 new_name.dtb CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mno-thumb-interwork -marm -fuse-ld=bfd -fmacro-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0=/usr/src/debug/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0=/usr/src/debug/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source=/usr/src/kernel   LD=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld.bfd
| make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/boot/dts/new_name.dtb'.  Stop.
| make[1]: *** [/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/Makefile:1265: new_name.dtb] Error 2
| make: *** [/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/Makefile:179: sub-make] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Execution of '/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/temp/run.do_compile.57871' failed with exit code 1:
|   GEN     Makefile
|   CALL    /home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
|   CALL    /home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/scripts/checksyscalls.sh
|   CHK     include/generated/compile.h
|   Kernel: arch/arm/boot/Image is ready
|   Kernel: arch/arm/boot/zImage is ready
| make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/boot/dts/new_name.dtb'.  Stop.
| make[1]: *** [/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/Makefile:1265: new_name.dtb] Error 2
| make: *** [/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/build/tmp/work-shared/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd/kernel-source/Makefile:179: sub-make] Error 2
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| 
ERROR: Task (/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/../meta-atmel/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-at91_5.4.81.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 6463 tasks of which 6457 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/poky/../meta-atmel/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-at91_5.4.81.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Please help and let me know if I missed any required information from my side.

Thank you and Regards,

Sohil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using `devtool modify linux-at91` to modify the linux kernel source-tree. This will create a linux-at91 folder in your `${TOPDIR}/workspace/sources/linux-at91`. If you don't know your ${TOPDIR}, try to use `bitbake -e <recipe-name> | grep "TOPDIR"`. `bitbake -e` will print your entire metadata for that recipe, here you can use grep to find the assignments of different variables. (like your KERNEL_DEVICETREE)

> `${TOPDIR}/workspace/sources/linux-at91`

This will be the source tree for your linux-at91 recipe.

Copy your dts files into `${TOPDIR}/workspace/sources/linux-at91/arch/arm/boot/dts`.

Modify the Makefile to include your dts, as pointed out by @BelHadjSalem TALEL (Thanks!).

Commit these changes and generate a patch.

In your own layer, under `recipes-kernel/linux-at91/linux-at91` place this patch file. Add `recipes-kernel/linux-at91/linux-at91.bbappend` to include this patch as below:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://0001-add-dts-file.patch"
```

---

Now to build your custom-machine, add `conf/machine/custom-machine.conf` and add an entry for your custom KERNEL_DEVICETREE like shown [here](https://github.com/OE4T/meta-tegra/blob/master/conf/machine/jetson-nano-devkit-emmc.conf#L18)

```
# This will inherit your base machine
require conf/machine/sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd.conf

KERNEL_DEVICETREE = "your-dts-file.dtb"
```

---

Overall, your layer will have following files:

```
- conf/layer.conf
- conf/machine/custom-machine.conf (Contains the above settings)
- recipes-kernel/linux-at91/linux-at91/0001-add-dts-file.patch
- recipes-kernel/linux-at91/linux-at91/linux-at91.bbappend
```

Answer (score 7):

Linux kernel devices trees are located in :

```
/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/git/arch/arm/boot/dts
```

Note that sources are in `git` and final build is in `build`.

You have to make sure that `new_name.dtb` present in the main Makefile:

```
/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/git/arch/arm/boot/dts/Makfile

+dtb-$(CONFIG_SOC_AT91SAM9) += new_name.dtb
```

Now the new device tree must be added to the `KERNEL_DEVICETREE` variable and that tells Yocto what Kernel device trees to build and ship into the boot partition so that u-boot load one of them into RAM while booting the board:

```
KERNEL_DEVICETREE += "new_name.dtb"
```

Now, after you understand how device tree are placed in the kernel, you can make this automatic, you create a `bbappend` recipe to your `linux-at91` kernel main recipe and add your custom device tree there.

```
meta-local/
  recipes-kernel/
     linux/
       files/
          new_custom.dts
       linux-at91_%.bbappend
```

Now, you need to copy your new dts file before compiling the kernel (do_compile) , the best moment is after do_configure:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI_append = " file://new_custom.dts"
do_configure_append(){
 cp ${WORKDIR}/new_custom.dts ${S}/arch/arm/boot/dts
 echo "dtb-$(CONFIG_SOC_AT91SAM9) += new_dts.dtb" >> ${S}/arch/arm/boot/dts/Makefile
}
```

Now, your new device tree will be compiled, and any compilation errors may be due to syntax error.

After knowing that the device tree is compiled and added to `KERNEL_DEVICETREE`, this means that it is present in the boot partition along side with all other device trees also in `KERNEL_DEVICETREE` variable, but u-boot loads only one of them in the RAM before loading the Linux kernel, and that device tree is set in your u-boot target `defconfig` file present in:

```
/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot-.../<version>/git/configs/your_machine_defconfig
```

you can find `your_machine_defconfig` in `UBOOT_CONFIG` variable in your machine configuration file which is located in your board's BSP layer:

```
meta-<board>/conf/machine/<board>.conf
```

After locating the defconfig you can find a variable `DEFAULT_FDT_FILE`.

At first, do not change it, just build your image, and pause at uboot stage and `printenv` to see the `fdt_file` variable and set it to your `new_name.dtb` file and `saveenv` to save it for every boot.

If that is okay, you can now patch your uboot defconfig file to set the new device tree file.

**Yocto tip:**

`${WORKDIR}` in the Kernel recipe points to:

```
/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/
```

`${S}` point to the git directory under `${WORKDIR}`

```
/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/git
```

that's why I copied the new device tree from `${WORKDIR}`

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand how dts is called and where to place it. But what file do I add the patch in do compile //FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI_append = " file://new_custom.dts"
do_configure_append(){
 cp ${WORKDIR}/new_custom.dts ${S}/arch/arm/boot/dts
 echo "dtb-$(CONFIG_SOC_AT91SAM9) += new_dts.dtb" >> ${S}/arch/arm/boot/dts/Makefile
}
which file is this patch to be added?

Comment: In linux-at91_%.bbappend

Comment: I seem to run into errors while I run bitbake can you help me verify where I mess up? ERROR: linux-at91-5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: linux-at91-5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/fakhruddin/workspace/Freshair/my_dir/FA_build/tmp/work/sama5d27_wlsom1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/5.4+gitAUTOINC+3dba8c9991-r0/temp/run.do_compile.157157' failed with exit code 1:                                  Also after someones suggestion I moved my build folder one directory up and also placed my downloads and sstate cache in same directory

Comment: This ERROR log is not clear at all, you need to share the full error log, and also share what you did exactly and what custom layer you have that appends to the linux recipe

Comment: It worked! I had some syntax errors in the dts file. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM I'm following this in branch Kirkstone for a Beaglebone machine. I can see that the Makefile has changed (adding to CONFIG_SOC_AM33XX), my dts is in the dts folder and no errors show compiling the kernel. How can I debug this to find out what am I doing wrong? I can't find my .dtb in the work folder. Why do you use new_custom.dts and new_dts.dtb? Is that a typo for new_custom.dtb or the dtb may have a different name?

Answer (score 1):

Just for information on great response by @BelHadjSalem: instead of manually copying dts file by 'do_configure_append', we can use [subdir](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SRC_URI) too.
so instead of

```
do_configure_append() {
    cp ${WORKDIR}/new_custom.dts ${S}/arch/arm/boot/dts
}
```

just we need:

```
SRC_URI_append = " file://new_custom.dts;subdir=git/arch/arm/boot/dts"
```